# Double Table JOIN Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: sql, mysql

I've been trying to rack my brain for a reason as to why I keep getting this error back:

> 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Service.name' in 'field list'

I have a few tables I need to gather information from - A Visit table which stores foreign keys for User & Service tables - the other two tables I am needing to pull information from.

When I run the following query, I get back the expected results:

```
SELECT Visit.id AS visitId, Visit.serviceId, Visit.currentFillCount, Visit.active, Service.name, Service.category, Service.type
FROM Visit
LEFT JOIN Service ON Service.id = Visit.serviceId
LIMIT 1000;
```

However, when I try to also join on the User table, I get the error:

> 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Service.name' in 'field list'

```
SELECT User.id AS userId, User.dateOfBirth, User.email, Visit.id AS visitId, Visit.serviceId, Visit.currentFillCount, Visit.active, Service.name, Service.category, Service.type
FROM Visit
LEFT JOIN User ON User.id = Visit.userId;
LEFT JOIN Service ON Service.id = Visit.serviceId
LIMIT 1000;
```

The columns are there - they get returned along with Visit information when running the first query. I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong in the second query that is causing this error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the semicolon after first join a typo?

Comment: Pretty sure that first comment nailed it.

Comment: @user2260040 Definitely a typo, thank you for pointing that out!